# Using Ptrace makes SIGSEGV handle routine not working

Tags: c, debugging, signals, segmentation-fault, ptrace

I'm new to ptrace and I'm not able to solve this problem.
I've copied and edited a simple debugger made with the ptrace system call and I'm trying to debug a test program that just makes use of a SIGSEGV handler... basically what I'm doing with the dummy program is:

> ```
>     void segv_handler(int signum){
>   printf("I'm inside the routine\n");
> }
>
> void main(){
>
>   int h;
>
>   signal(SIGSEGV, segv_handler);
>   printf("Hello\n");
>   raise(SIGSEGV);
>   printf("Hello2\n");
>
> }
> ```

Easy.. The point is that my debugger gets notified of the SIGSEGV, in fact I get on the screen the result of the SIGSEGV printf, while the program doesn't print "I'm inside the routine", meaning that the segv_handler is beeing ignored. How is this possible? And how can I solve this problem?

```
    if(WIFSTOPPED(status)){
        switch(WSTOPSIG(status)){

            case SIGTRAP:
                //printf("SIGTRAP\n");
                break;

            case SIGSTOP:
                printf("SIGSTOP\n");
                break;

            case SIGSEGV:
                printf("SIGSEGV\n");
                //ptrace();
                break;

            default:
                printf("else\n");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: GDB has ability to pass custom signals to the traced process. May be GDB sources will show you how it is achieved ?

Comment: The SIGSEGV handler isn't being ignored, it just hasn't been invoked yet because ptrace has told the OS to stop the target when a signal is delivered to it. You might want to try `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, target, 0, SIGSEGV)` to continue the target while delivering the signal to it.

Comment: thank you! I solved it!I was doing instead: ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, target, 0, 0)